# Place a button over UICollectionView and maintain the scroll

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and a UIButton over it (on the right edge). But in the button's frame the collectionView loses it's scrolling property.

I wan't to know if there's any way to maintain both interactions, the Button touch up inside and the CollectionView scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to do that, but instead of buttons I used the UITapGestureRecognizer as [rounak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424406/rounak) suggests:

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "collectionViewDidReceiveTap:")
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

As I wanted a specific rect to be "tapable" I've implemented the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, this piece of code do this:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let collectionViewCurrentCell = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: Int(self.currentPage), inSection: 0))
    let cellFrameInSuperview = collectionView.convertRect(collectionViewCurrentCell!.frame, toView: self)

    if gestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UITapGestureRecognizer) && CGRectContainsPoint(cellFrameInSuperview, touch.locationInView(self)) {

        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Where the cellFrameInSuperview should be the region where the TapGesture shouldn't do anything. But different from the UIButton, the scroll continues to work in all the Collection bounds.

If you have any questions about how, or why it works, leave a comment.

Comment: Out of all solutions this is the one that worked best for me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a button, use a view with a tap gesture recognizer and let that tap gesture recognizer work simultaneously with the scrollview's pan gesture.

Comment: Well, ok, I used it, it works, but now I lost any "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" call of my collectionView Delegate